# Running web application with rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I need to work with a rails application on Mac OS 10.8 but I am having troubles starting the rails server.

I installed Ruby and I am using version ruby-1.9.2-p320 and I installed rvm and rails.
Following the Ruby Getting Started Guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) what I need now is simply navigate into my application folder and run the command:

```
rails server
```

but I get this error

```
git://github.com/archiloque/rest-client.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

When running the command `bundle install` I get stuck with the following error

```
Could not find gem 'rest-client (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/archiloque/rest-client.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'rest-client (>= 0) ruby'
```

What am I missing?

Strange thing I just noticed is that when running

```
gem rails install
```

I am notified that rails has been correctly installed (`Successfully installed rails-3.2.13`), but when checking its version

```
rails --version
```

I receive again the error message

```
git://github.com/archiloque/rest-client.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

The content of my Gemfile follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.5'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'devise', '2.1.2'
gem 'rest-client', :git => 'git://github.com/archiloque/rest-client.git'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rspec-rails', group: [:test,:development]
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem "rb-readline"

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :test do
gem 'debugger'
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'vcr'
gem 'fakeweb'
gem 'rb-fsevent', :require => false
gem 'guard-rspec'
gem 'growl'
gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :development do
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'capistrano-ext'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'
end
```

Comment: If you followed all the steps in that tutorial you can start your server without any problems

Comment: Then i missed a step somewhere. Do you suggest I uninstall everything before trying to follow the guide again?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Gemfile ?

Comment: Content of the Gemfile added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of `rest-client` moved the repository, see here (https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client).

Use this in your Gemfile `gem 'rest-client', :git => 'git://github.com/rest-client/rest-client.git'`

Comment: I did not notice that! Thanks!
But I keep receiving the error : `git://github.com/rest-client/rest-client.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run 'bundle install'`.
And when I run 'bundle install':
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at
http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:103:in `new': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Comment: Did you try the troubleshooting steps from the link you posted?

If not, try first removing the lock file `rm Gemfile.lock`, then run `bundle install` again.

Comment: I tried a few possibilities, but i fairly don't know the one that solved the problem!
Now the issue should be solved! Thanks!